# Using a non-const object for a const parameter

Tags: c++, const-correctness

Perhaps I don't understand the purpose of `const` in class methods.

Let's say I want to implement a container storing objects of type `Foo`, but my container promises not to alter any of the `Foo` objects themselves.

```
struct Foo
{
    int faz;
    Foo() : faz(0) {}
};

class FooContainer
{
    public:
        FooContainer() : _foos(), _numFoos(0) {}

        void addFoo(const Foo* foo)
        {
            _foos[_numFoos] = foo;
            _numFoos++;
        }

    private:
        const Foo* _foos[10];
        int        _numFoos;
};

int main()
{

    FooContainer fc;
    Foo foo;

    fc.addFoo(&foo);

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine until I want to grab a `Foo` out of the container and do something to it.  Let's say I add a method to `FooContainer`:

```
Foo* getFoo(int index) const
{
    return _foos[index];
}
```

I get an error saying that I'm trying to convert a `const Foo*` to a `Foo*`, which I guess is true because of the `return`.

So then I put a `const` in front of it:

```
const Foo* getFoo(int index) const
{
    return _foos[index];
}
```

Great, that works.  Now, try to get the `Foo` and do something with it in `main()`:

```
Foo* foo2 = fc.getFoo(0);
```

Now I get the same error, converting from a `const Foo*` to a `Foo*`.  Again, I agree.  But of course if I put a `const` in front of my `foo2`, I can't change the contents of `foo2`.

```
const Foo* foo2 = fc.getFoo(0);
foo2->faz = 3;   // error: assignment of member 'Foo::faz' in read-only object
```

So, how do I tell my users I ain't gonna change their precious objects inside my container?

I tried making `_foos` a non-`const`, but keeping the `const` on the `addFoo(const Foo* foo)`, but still got an invalid conversion from `const Foo*` to `Foo*`.

Comment: You tell your users by giving them exactly what they put into your container, a `const` object. Which proves that you could not possibly change it.

Comment: It seems you're trying to say that `FooContainer` won't modify the container; however, users can call `FooContainer::getFoo` and they can modify it.

Comment: If you must return mutable outputs, the appropriate way to tell users that your container won't modify the objects here is through documentation.

Comment: @Tas, I'm not trying to say that `FooContainer` won't modify the container.  I want to say that `FooContainer` won't modify any of the `Foo`'s pointed to by the array inside the container.  But still allow the user to modify them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I still want the user to be able to modify their own object.

Comment: Then you can't store pointers to `const` objects in your container.

Comment: "How do I tell my users I ain't gonna change their precious objects inside my container?"  - write documentation if necessary.  The "default" semantics for containers is that you get out what you put in, they don't change the objects for no reason

Comment: "_How do I tell my users I ain't gonna change their precious objects inside my container?_" - why would you do that since you intend to acctually give non-const access to the objects? A user of `FooContainer` doesn't care if it's changed inside `FooContainer` or by something else that got access to the pointer.

Comment: Storing a pointer to a non-const object into a container of const pointers requires conversion from non-const to const. That can be done implicitly. Conversion is needed in the other way, from const to non-const, but that needs to be explicit via `const_cast`. If the user wants to store non-const objects into a container of const pointers, the user should be the one to strip off the `const` when it wants to modify an object accessed from the container, eg: `Foo foo; fc.addFoo(&foo); const Foo* foo2 = fc.getFoo(0); const_cast<Foo*>(foo2)->faz = 3;`

Answer (score 2):

> So, how do I tell my users I ain't gonna change their precious objects inside my container?

You don't, and shouldn't. Your container *delegates* the changing of their precious objects to someone else, so it shouldn't make a promise it doesn't intend to keep.